# Why does this Scala line return a Unit?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Here's a bit of Scala code to sum the values from 1 to 9 which are divisible by 3 or 5. Why does line 5 return a Unit and not a Boolean type?

```
object Sample {

    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val answer = (1 until 10).foldLeft(0) ((result, current) => {
            if ((current % 3 == 0) || (current % 5 == 0)) {
                result + current
            }
        })

        println(answer)
    }

}
```

Comment: might wanna tag this project-euler-spoiler ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to spoil. Wasn't really thinking about that when I posted. I would edit it out, but I can't edit other's answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The if expression has a type of Unit because there is no else clause.  Thus sometimes it returns nothing (Unit) so the entire expression has type Unit.

(I assume you meant to ask why it didn't return Int, not Boolean)

Comment: You're correct. I didn't realize what was actually going on - I'm really new to functional programming. What's the best way to handle this? Adding an else with result + 0?

Comment: move the `result +` portion out of the `if` block (there's no need to repeat it), and make it `result + if (...) current else 0`

Comment: This isn't correct. The if expr has type `AnyVal`. The `Unit` in the error is the unit value supplied in the else expr. It knows an `Int` is required because the `B` type param is already solved by inspecting the first arg list. Because the else is absent, confusingly the caret points to the if expr in the error message.

Answer (score 9):

Can we ever be **too** idiomatic? YES WE CAN!

```
Set(3,5).map(k => Set(0 until n by k:_*)).flatten.sum
```

[Edit]

Daniel's suggestion looks better:

```
Set(3,5).flatMap(k => 0 until n by k).sum
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use `flatMap`?

Comment: In fact, if you do so, you can even shorten it to `Set(3,5).flatMap(k => 0 until n by k).sum`.

Comment: Nice one. Very... err.. arithmetic :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution:

```
scala> val answer = (1 until 10) filter( current => (current % 3 == 0) || (current % 5 == 0)) sum
answer: Int = 23
```

Notice the filter instead of if's.

Another one in a even more idiomatic Scala:

```
( for( x <- 1 until 10 if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 ) yield x ) sum
```

Comment: +1 Another great answer. Thanks for helping me learn a few different ways.

Answer (score 4):

The closest working code to what you did is this:

```
object Euler {
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val answer = (1 until 10).foldLeft(0) ((result, current) =>
            if ((current % 3 == 0) || (current % 5 == 0))
                result + current
            else
                result
        )

        println(answer)
    }
}
```