# Return type in If expression

Tags: scala

I am learning scala and can't understand why:

```
def signum(arg: Int) = {
    if(arg > 0 ) 1
    else if(arg < 0) -1
    else 0
}
```

Has `Int` as return type `signum (arg: Int): Int`

But

```
def signum(arg: Int) = {
    if(arg > 0 ) 1
    else if(arg < 0) -1
    else if(arg == 0) 0
}
```

Has `AnyVal` `signum (arg: Int): AnyVal`

Comment: (admittedly not easy to fulltext search for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038741/why-does-this-scala-line-return-a-unit

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the absence of an explicit `else`, Scala assumes this:

```
else ()
```

Where `()` is the value of `Unit`. It's the value returned by `println` or assignment to `var`, for example.

This can be easily verified:

```
scala> val x = if (false) 1
x: AnyVal = ()

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Unit]
res3: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 24):

It happens because in the second case you have not specified final `else` part. In this case the return type of this missing branch would be `Unit`. So Scala compiler infers `AnyVal` as a common parent of `Int` and `Unit`.

you can try to add explicit return type to the function signature:

```
def signum(arg: Int): Int = ...
```

It will not compile with following error:

```
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
    else if(arg == 0) 0
         ^
one error found
```

So the compiler tells you that result type of the last `if` is actually `Unit` and not `Int`.

Comment: Adding a type annotation to all public members is a very good idea. First it prevents errors like this. And second it is a kind of documentation. Third, sometimes you want a certain (general) type to be returned, but the compiler would infer the most specific one, e.g. you want _Seq_ instead of _List_.