# Why "if as expression not statement" is cool?

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming, semantics, tradeoff

I have heard few talks on modern programming languages like scala (and few other languages whose names I cannot remember right now), and often got the sense of excitement when the speakers were talking like: "if is an expression in our programming language, it returns value, WOW". So the question is, why an when `if` being an expression rather than a statement like in `C` is better?

Comment: You mean like this?  `foo = x == 1 ? x : y;`

Comment: Because it returns a value, so that you can do something (or rather: anything) with it?

Comment: Here's why it's not cool: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4038741/1296806

Comment: I'd suggest sticking around for the second day of talks, when they'll be excited about other stuff.

Comment: @Bergi indeed, often you wind up doing `Any` thing with it, depending on the LUB of the branches.

Comment: @som-snytt this is not a reason why it is not cool. It just shows a lack of knowledge  of the programmer. And the case you postet would have the same problems if "IF" is a statemant.
For scala I would say "it is cool" cos it fits the needs of scala. You want to use val if possible so you can't do it like c/++/# or java and just  reassign your variable.
Besides, I find it more readable, cos you read it like "variable declaration =  variable def". It is obvious where the value comes from.
And you can't forget a branch, cos the type would be wrong and in most cases won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with dealing with **values** instead of dealing with **(re)assignments.** Values are simple and (re)assignments are hard;
Consider java where **if construct** is a statement, and also **blocks {}** are also sort of statements, and **try** is also kind of statement, and neither of them could return value:

```
Object someObject = null; // you'll have to scan through all 
// of the scope below to find out where `someObject` got assigned from

try {
  // ... and now imagine this if statements nested with try statements like
  // 20 times, and it's hard to  refactor them into multiple mehtods, 
  // because they are not logically connected

  if (someCondition) {
     someObject = <someValue>; 
  } else {
     someObject = <anotherValue>;
  }
} catch (Exception e) { ....};
```

compare with scala, where all those statements are actually expressions and can return values:

```
val someObject = try {
   if (someCondition) {
      "someResult" 
   } else {
     { "something else" }
   }
} catch { case Exception e => "someDefaultValue"; }
```

Now I argue that scala version is plainly simpler for understanding))) `someObject` is **value** so it got assigned one time, and I'm not bothered that somewhere below it got reassigned. I don't have to move variables outside `if` and `try` blocks just to keep them visible to the outside. And if I have a lot of nested if blocks, I still can deduce what result value will be at each level just by looking at it, while in java I need to keep whole method, and in fact execute it in my head to be able to deduce what top level variables got updated and when.
BTW java has `?: operator` but it is very limited compared to scala's if expression (mainly because you can't use brakets within).

Answer (score 1):

It may be surprising for some, but there are languages that don't have "statements" at all. One example would be Haskell. In such circumstances there is no choice than having `if` expressions.

Note that any decent imperative language has `if` expressions, too. It's just called and written differently, like, for example:

```
cond ? "yes" : "no"
```

Incidentally, imperative languages *short circuit* such an expression, which is slang for *lazy evaluation of the 2nd and 3rd expression* (just like Haskell does it anyway).